# Terraform operations work in azure for everything but the migration of state to blob storage

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-blob-storage

When running terraform plan and apply, everything works fine. When trying to migrate state to an azure blob the following occurs:
`→  terraform init -migrate-state

Initializing the backend...
Terraform detected that the backend type changed from "local" to "azurerm".

Initializing modules...
╷
│ Error: Error inspecting states in the "local" backend:
│     containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthenticationFailed" Message="Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:19d51fce-001e-0001-26cf-fa1cb6000000\nTime:2023-10-09T16:40:54.4441668Z"
│
│ Prior to changing backends, Terraform inspects the source and destination
│ states to determine what kind of migration steps need to be taken, if any.
│ Terraform failed to load the states. The data in both the source and the
│ destination remain unmodified. Please resolve the above error and try again.`

We've reset the credentials, manually created the storage account and container. We use a service principal to login and terraform pulls those creds from the shell ENV. Here is the tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.75.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = ">=2.43.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
}

provider "azuread" {
  client_id     = var.client_id
  client_secret = var.client_secret
  tenant_id     = var.tenant_id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "primary_resource_group" {
  name     = var.primary_rg_name
  location = var.primary_location

  tags = {
    creator      = var.creator
  }
}

locals {
  scope = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.primary_resource_group.name
  location                 = var.storage_account_location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"

  blob_properties {
    versioning_enabled = true
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = 7
    }
    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = 21
    }
  }

  tags = {
    creator      = var.creator
    product_line = "Astra"
  }
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    container_name       = "astra-dev-qa"
    key                  = "qa.terraform.tfstate"
    resource_group_name  = "rg_astra-dev-qa"
    storage_account_name = "astradevqa"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to perform operations to work in Azure for everything in the migration of state to blob storage I was able to provision the requirment successfully.

It seems you're running into multiple issues simultaneously when trying to migrate your Terraform state to Azure Blob Storage.

1. **Authentication Error**: The error message suggests an authentication failure when trying to list blobs. This could be due to a few reasons:

   - The Service Principal's credentials are incorrect.
   - The Service Principal does not have the necessary permissions to access the storage account.
   - The information in the `backend "azurerm"` configuration might be wrong (like `container_name`, `resource_group_name`, etc.).
2. **Terraform Configuration for Azure Backend**: The current Terraform configuration shows how you're defining resources in Azure. However, when setting up a backend, you typically need to provide authentication details for the backend too

**My terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.75.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = ">=2.43.0"
    }
  }


  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name   = "v-sakavya"
    storage_account_name  = "myvksbstorageaccount"
    container_name        = "astravksb"
    key                   = "qa.terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
}

provider "azuread" {
  client_id     = var.client_id
  client_secret = var.client_secret
  tenant_id     = var.tenant_id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "primary_resource_group" {
  name     = var.primary_rg_name
  location = var.primary_location

  tags = {
    creator = var.creator
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                     = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.primary_resource_group.name
  location                 = var.storage_account_location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"

  blob_properties {
    versioning_enabled = true
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = 7
    }
    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = 21
    }
  }

  tags = {
    creator = var.creator
  }
}
```

##### variables.tf:

```
variable "client_id" {
  description = "The Azure Service Principal client ID"
  type        = string
}

variable "client_secret" {
  description = "The Azure Service Principal client secret"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "subscription_id" {
  description = "The Azure subscription ID"
  type        = string
}

variable "tenant_id" {
  description = "The Azure tenant ID"
  type        = string
}

variable "primary_rg_name" {
  description = "The primary resource group name"
  type        = string
}

variable "primary_location" {
  description = "The Azure region for resources"
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure storage account"
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_location" {
  description = "The Azure region for the storage account"
  type        = string
}

variable "creator" {
  description = "Tag for the creator of the resources"
  type        = string
}
```

##### output.tf:

```
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.primary_resource_group.name
}

output "storage_account_name" {
  value = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
}
```

**Output:**

Follow the mentioned commands here to achieve the requirement youre looking for.

```
terraform init -backend-config="client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" -backend-config="client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" -backend-config="tenant_id=YOUR_TENANT_ID" -backend-config="subscription_id=YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
```

[image]

```
terraform apply -var "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" -var "client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" -var "tenant_id=YOUR_TENANT_ID" -var "subscription_id=YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" -var "primary_rg_name=YOUR_RG_NAME" -var "primary_location=YOUR_LOCATION" -var "storage_account_name=YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME" -var "storage_account_location=YOUR_STORAGE_LOCATION" -var "creator=YOUR_NAME"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what I have except I'm sourcing from environment variables. This is working in other subscriptions, just not this one.

Comment: In that case, check with your permission mentioned in the solution wait for some sync time, and try again.